# Magento frontend cookie

Tags: frontend, cookie

In a list of cookies I can see "frontend", "adminhtml" and "external_no_cache" cookie name. 
I need to write a list of all cookies, their purpose and expiration date.
Can anyone help me? What are these cookies for? Where can I get more information?

Another thing, when I use an online cookie checker (for example http://www.cookie-checker.com/), the resoult I get is: the only cookie on my site is "frontend".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use FireBug plugin to see all request information or print the **`$_COOKIES`** auto global variable.

Check following information

> Cookie Name --> Information

**`CART`** --> The association with your shopping cart.

**`CATEGORY_INFO`** --> Stores the category info on the page, that allows to display pages more quickly.

**`COMPARE`** --> The items that you have in the Compare Products list.

**`CURRENCY`** --> Your preferred currency

**`CUSTOMER`** --> An encrypted version of your customer id with the store.

**`CUSTOMER_AUTH`** --> An indicator if you are currently logged into the store.

**`CUSTOMER_INFO`** --> An encrypted version of the customer group you belong to.

**`CUSTOMER_SEGMENT_IDS`** --> Stores the Customer Segment ID

**`EXTERNAL_NO_CACHE`** --> A flag, which indicates whether caching is disabled or not.

**`FRONTEND`** --> You sesssion ID on the server.

**`GUEST-VIEW`** --> Allows guests to edit their orders.

**`LAST_CATEGORY`** --> The last category you visited.

**`LAST_PRODUCT`** --> The most recent product you have viewed.

**`NEWMESSAGE`** --> Indicates whether a new message has been received.

**`NO_CACHE`** --> Indicates whether it is allowed to use cache.

**`PERSISTENT_SHOPPING_CART`** --> A link to information about your cart and viewing history if you have asked the site.

**`POLL`** --> The ID of any polls you have recently voted in.

**`POLLN`** --> Information on what polls you have voted on.

**`RECENTLYCOMPARED`** --> The items that you have recently compared.

**`STF`** --> Information on products you have emailed to friends.

**`STORE`** --> The store view or language you have selected.

**`USER_ALLOWED_SAVE_COOKIE`** --> Indicates whether a customer allowed to use cookies.

**`VIEWED_PRODUCT_IDS`** --> The products that you have recently viewed.

**`WISHLIST`** --> An encrypted list of products added to your Wishlist.

**`WISHLIST_CNT`** --> The number of items in your Wishlist.

Comment: If it helps you please accept it. it will help other users